# Does Eclipse Installer eclipse-inst-win64.exe version 2020-03 (4.15.0) support Angular and "ng serve" without additional plugins?

Tags: angularjs, angular, eclipse

I'm just started with Angular and have been using Eclipse for years (lots of years).  There is an install option for Eclipse (version 2020-03 (4.15.0) build id 20200313-1211) that seems to suggest that it supports Angular out of the box.

This is what the installer looks like:

[image]

This is the "About" page after it is installed:

[image]

Will this install support Angular development out of the box (is there a built in Angular editor)?

Can I run and debug "ng serve" from this install without additional plugins? If no, what plug in do I need for this?  If yes, how?

How do I create a project from existing Angular files (I have an existing project that has angular.json, package.json, package-lock.json, proxy.config.json, tsconfig.json, ts files, etc.)?

And here's the installation details:
[image]

I see other postings but they all seem to be for older versions or other products.
https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/february/article1.php 
https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/how-to-import-an-angular-project/ 
https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse/issues/19 
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-angular-ide-eclipse-hello-world-example

Comment: Why not try it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ***Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers* 2020-03** has **built-in Angular support** (the *Eclipse Installer* is to choose the IDE package to install only).

See:

- [Eclipse Wild Web Developer website](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) (Eclipse Wild Web Developer is part of the *Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers* 2020-03)
- [My video, where the Angular support can be seen for a moment](https://youtu.be/XoUvOTiVaDc?t=680)